# Next.js Run dev Issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[image]

I tried hardly to run next.js app

When i type "npm run dev" or "npx next dev"

it simpley appear for 1 seconds and quit by itself

Comment: Run this command `node -p "process.arch"` if return x86, uninstall Nodejs and try to install an x64 one.